# How does ObservableCollection in the .NET Projection map to WinRT?

Tags: observablecollection, windows-runtime

Looking at the Windows Runtime reference at the Microsoft site the only relevant collection I can find is the [IObservableVector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226052.aspx). Does the .NET Projection ObservableCollection get mapped to that WinRT interface? If so, hows does it handle the fact that ObservableCollection implements multiple other interfaces that the IObservableVector does not?

**UPDATE**: The ObservableCollection does work with Windows 8 Consumer Preview and can be bound to an ItemsSource and will correctly update the XAML control when items are added/removed from the ObservableCollection.

Comment: There's no concrete implementation for the interface yet.  Everybody is writing their own, arbitrarily from a google hit:  http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/01/03/Hello-ObservableVector-goodbye-ObservableCollection.aspx

Comment: But I created a test app that binds an ObservableCollection<T> to a ListBox.ItemsSource last night for the Windows 8 Consumer Preview. It works fine and as I add or remove objects from the ObservableCollection the ListBox was corrected updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking on the Microsoft Windows Runtime Forum it seems that there is no mapping at the moment to the IObservableVector runtime type from any CLR type.